# Where can I get a Geneva Mastercraft hinge?

Tags: hinges

[image]

This hinge has worn out (it's about 25 years old. Sorry for the gross dirty picture).  I called MasterCraft, and they don't make it any more.  I've searched the web for it and can't find it.  Does anyone know if I can get one, or if not, what I can use for a substitute? I'm very handy, but don't have many power tools.

Comment: Troll ebay or a Habitat for Humanity Re-Store, perhaps. Shopping questions are off-topic, though, so let's concentrate on "pretty much any other cabinet hinge" particularly since it appears to be "32mm standard" with the round hole mount.

Comment: I could probably dig a couple of those out of my IKEA-bits-and-bobs box, together with dampeners...

Comment: Definitely 32mm-mount "euro hinge". The question is going to be finding a model with the right amount of overlay for your door, and that permits opening the door to the angle this cabinet was designed for (110 degrees?). Thinking an existing hinge to a woodworking store, where someone can help you find the right match, may be simplest; otherwise I'd say look at a catalog to see which measurements to match.

Answer (score 8):

The "GENEVA BY MASTERCRAFT" label is on the little piece that pops in to the hinge. It is only cosmetic and there are two reasons it is designed that way:

- It allows flipping it upside down (for left vs. right opening doors)
- It allows replacement for different "manufacturers"

As with many other products, these hinges are made by various companies to standard specifications and then bundled/installed by other companies with their products.

No power tools needed.

- Unscrew the hinge (4 screws, phillips head screwdriver).
- Unscrew any additional hinges on the same door. (Because otherwise the door will not hang safely.)
- Take the hinge to a hardware store. Some stores will have more variety of odd parts like this than others, though this particular hinge looks pretty standard to me.
- Buy a replacement hinge with the same dimensions. If you can't find one with the same dimensions (and don't have additional local stores to check) then try an online seller like [cabinetparts.com](https://www.cabinetparts.com/c/hinges/european-cabinet-hinges). (I have no connection, that is the first one that Google found for me and it looks like the right type of seller. There are others.)
- When installing the new hinge, you *may* want to use slightly wider screws (but same length) in order to get enough grip on the door and the cabinet.

Comment: Also worth checking woodworking stores like Rockler and Woodcrafters (no affiliation with either), as they cater to woodworkers and have and/or can get a wider variety of sizes/styles.

Comment: A trick with re-using the screw is I insert a toothpick into the existing hole. This gives it the grip needed and fills in any loose material. Add more than one or even add wood glue if the material is really falling apart. Since the hinge allows adjustments, misalignment can be easily fixed.

Comment: @Nelson I am well aware of [the toothpick trick](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/157508/was-my-approach-to-repairing-stripped-holes-in-a-door-jamb-appropriate/157510#157510)

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but are those two screws on the right [Pozidriv screws](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/106688) and not Phillips screws? I can't tell for the ones on the left though

Comment: @cocomac Maybe. But to be honest, for a few little screws like these Philips will probably do just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Blum (the name stamped on the hinge next to the plastic nameplate) is a huge manufacturer of cabinet/drawer hardware.  They should have what you need.

That said, it appears to be a pretty standard hidden cabinet door hinge and almost any manufacturer should have something with similar enough specs to fit.